# Calculating percentage in hive

Tags: hadoop, percentage, hiveql

I am having a little trouble getting the percentage.

```
colA | cloB | colC
4    |  a   |  y
5    |  b   |  y
7    |  a   |  n
8    |  a   |  y
------------------
Output:
a 67%
b 100%
```

I have to get the percentage of colC(all the 'y') for each letter in colB.

I have been able to get both totals seperatly but can't seem to get the percentage to work.

 Gets the total 'y' for a,b(colB);

```
SELECT colB, COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE colC = '"y"' GROUP BY colB;
Output:
a   2
b   1
```

Gets totals overall total for colB

```
SELECT COUNT(colC) FROM tbl WHERE colC = '"y"';
Output:
4
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the IF UDF to avoid the join

```
SELECT t1.colB,
   SUM( IF( colC == 'y', 1 , 0 ) )/ COUNT(*) * 100 as pct
FROM tbl t1
GROUP BY t1.colB;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not (yet :D) an expert in Hive but you can try a subquery like that :

```
SELECT 
    t1.colB,
    100*(count(colB)/sub.cnt)
FROM 
    tbl t1,
    (SELECT COUNT(colC) as cnt 
     FROM tbl 
     WHERE colC = 'y') sub
JOIN 
    tbl ON (sub.colC = tbl.colC))
GROUP BY 
    colB;
```

Ps : I'm not 100% sure and I can't test it actually, just trying to help.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the code. It gives me an error " FAILED ParseException line 1:47 missing EOF at ',' near 'tbl1'

Comment: Yes, my bad, in fact you can't just put a table and a subquery in the clause FROM just like that, i'm actually looking for a solution. I reedited, tell me. If it still doesn't run I will show you an example with union which i'm sure it works but not optimized :(

Comment: It says Failed to recognize predicate 't1'. Failed rule: 'kwInner' in join type specifier.